# wso2 apim (4.0.0) keeps returning too many attempts after updating changing business plan of subscription

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I subscribed to an api with 1.5k requests per week business plan in wso2 apim devportal. Then I exceeded allowed quota. But it keeps sending 429 too many attempts error even after upgrading my business plan to unlimited. Any tip is appreciated

Comment: Did you deploy a new revision after changing the business plans?

Comment: Why should I deploy new revision? I changed only business plan of my subscription from "1.5kPerReq" (custom)  to unlimited

Comment: I mean I didn't change rules of business plan itself, just chose another business plan from devportal

Comment: Did you generate a new token?

Comment: yes, I did, several times. I even checked the database if my subscription plan is updated. And it is indeed.

Comment: Were you able to restart the API Manager server and able to verify the behaviour? Also, do you have any advanced throttling policies engaged at the API Resource level?

Comment: Yes, only after restarting it works as it supposed to do. Furthermore, I have some custom defined throttling policies

Comment: Are you using a distributed setup in your environment? If yes, you have to recheck the configurations related to Event Hub components to update the API details in runtime. Since this is getting solved after a restart, please check on your Event Hub configurations in the API Manager instances.